# Unexpected behaviour of <use> in svg

Tags: html, svg

I stumbled upon a problem. 
I am using **Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m** - latest verstion.

The `<use>` seems to work OK on `<circle>` but not on `<foreignObject>` tag.

```
<svg height="400" width="400">
    <foreignObject id="first" x="120" y="120" width="180" height="180">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height: 800px">
            <ul>
                <li><strong>First</strong> item</li>
                <li>
                    <em>Second</em> item
                </li>
                <li>Thrid item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </foreignObject>

    <!--<circle id="first" cx="150" cy="50" r="100" fill="lime" />-->


    <polygon id="second" class="poly-in" points="300,200 200,300 100,200 200,0" style="fill:blue;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />

    <use id="use-first" xlink:href="#first" href="#first" />

    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

[This doesn't work (bug) ...](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz6XZ/) 
But, [I can get `<use>` to work when referencing a `<circle>`](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz6XZ/1/)
And, [I can get `<foreignObject>` to work when not referenced by a `<use>`](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz6XZ/2/)

I am very confused and don't know if I am misunderstanding something or is it a bug. I've been reading [w3c paper on SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElement) and cannot figure it out.

I am looking identical behaviour than in [example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz6XZ/1/) but for the code posted here with `<foreignObject>`.

Comment: Most browsers don't support foreign objects in a use element; the W3 specs you linked to only allow `<use>` to reference `<g>`, `<svg>` or a [graphics element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermGraphicsElement).  The specs don't describe the situation when you've got a foreign object *inside* a `<g>` or `<svg>`.  But again, not widely supported.  See [this thread on the W3 SVG mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2013May/0043.html) for more discussion (use the "next in thread" link to read all the responses).

Comment: @AmeliaBR - Your comment is a better answer than mine.  You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @gilly3  Done. Thanks for the nudge. I don't really like posting "it can't be done" answers, but sometimes they are appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "unexpected behaviour" is actually an expected -- if not very well documented -- limitation of the `<use>` element.

The [W3 specs you linked to](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElement) only allow  to reference ,  or a [graphics element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermGraphicsElement) -- a `<foreignObject>` tag is not a valid reference for `<use>`.

You could technically get around the specs by referencing a `<g>` or `<svg>` tag which then contains the `<foreignObject>` as a child.  However, most browsers don't support foreign objects in a `<use>` element however it is worded.

Although your example of a bulleted list is harmless, there would be serious implementation difficulties from supporting arbitrary copies of any and all HTML, especially when you factor in the way style properties are supposed to be inherited from the `<use>` element. [See this thread on the W3 SVG mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2013May/0043.html) for more discussion (use the "next in thread" link to read all the responses).

Browsers currently have [enough problems with interactive graphics properties and `<use>` elements](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/full/lshrp), I would not expect to see an extension of `<use>` to foreign objects any time soon (although hopefully SVG2 will have clearer language indicating that it *isn't* possible).

Working around the issue will really depend on the specifics of what you're trying to do.  @gilly3 made some suggestions.  You may need to resort to Javascript if you want to copy a large chunk of HTML for use in multiple contexts.

Comment: Thank you very much. Idea was to "lift" the :hovered element so it is seen in its entirety. The foreignObject contains label tag which controls a checkbox which then controls some elements of the page. The end result can be seen here: http://codepen.io/jaka_dirnbek/full/fvImi  PS: the jersey is the label

Comment: Interesting project.  If I'm understand it correctly, the foreign object is just there to create a clickable layer (controlling the checkbox) that is above some of the SVG and below the rest of it?  For something like that (where there isn't a lot of copied HTML content), it's probably easiest to just duplicate the mark-up.  Interaction on `<use>` elements has enough bugs even before you start dealing with HTML foreign objects!

Comment: Yeah, the idea is when one hovers above the jersey or the shorts they get colored and one can click it and triggers the label which has a for attr set. The input then controls parts of the site via :checked . I could just use JS but that would not be as much fun. The main problem I have with divs is that they are rectangular and when you use :hover the style is applied even if you are not hovering exactly on the thing you whish to apply the :hover selector. SVG helps here with its polygons. I have some ideas how I would implement this with divs. If I make anything I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your `<foreignObject>` in a `<switch>` and add a corresponding fallback element (such as `<text>`) you can reference the `<switch>` from the `<use>` and the fallback element will display.  Obviously, this is less than ideal.  And it doesn't work in FireFox or IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/Uz6XZ/4/

As an alternative, if your goal is just to bring the `<foreignObject>` to the front, I've found you can do so by specifying `position: relative` on the `<div>`.  That's a bit of a hack and only works in Chrome, not FireFox or IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/Uz6XZ/3/